# inital state not visible in devtools

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I have problem with ngrx simplest start up. Probably missing something

[image]

[image]

Isn' t it enough for devtools to display inital state list: [] ??

I have this [image]

Answer (score 2):

To view your store in the [Redux-Devtools](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/), you have to set up the `StoreDevtoolsModule` like described in the [NgRx documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools)

```js
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
    maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
    logOnly: environment.production, // Restrict extension to log-only mode
    autoPause: true, // Pauses recording actions and state changes when the extension window is not open
}),
```